# How to pass the id when a checkbox is checked in asp repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have an asp repeater that binds the list of orders by tracking number. I want to know how could I pass the id of the selected row when a checkbox is checked. I did this to bind the checked checkbox only.

## Repeater

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater2_ItemDataBound">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table class=" table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Order Type</th>
                <th>Job Name</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDisplayTitle" runat="server" /></td>
            <td><%#Eval("Order") %></td>
            <td><%#Eval("Job_Name") %></td>
            <td><%#Eval("Price") %></td>
        </tr>

    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <td>Subtotal:
        <asp:Label ID="lblSubtotal" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

## Code Behind

```
private void ConsolidateItems()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect"].ConnectionString);

    //======= Parameterized select Query.
    string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM Order_TB WHERE Tracking_Number=@tracking AND Status=@status";

    //====== Providning information to SQL command object about which query to 
    //====== execute and from where to get database connection information.
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, con);

    //===== Adding parameters/Values.
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tracking", hfid.Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", "Accepted");


    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        con.Open();
    }

    Repeater2.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    Repeater2.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Where do you want to pass gridview selected row ID?

Comment: I want to pass the ID when the confirm button is clicked (This button when clicked will update the row in the database) and in the subtotal part in the repeater's footer (to only add the prices of the checked checkbox)

Comment: After **CheckBox** control place a **HiddenField** control and bind **ID** into this control. After clicking on submit button loop gridview rows. Find and read checkboxes and hidden field and perform relevant operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On ASPX :

```
  <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBoxID" runat="server" OnCommand="doSomething_Checked" 
   CommandArgument="<%# Some Binding Information%>" CommandName="NameForArgument"> </asp:CheckBox>
```

On Code-Behind :

```
 protected void doSomething_Checked(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
   {

            CheckBox ctrl = (CheckBox)sender;
            RepeaterItem rpItem = ctrl.NamingContainer as RepeaterItem;
            if (rpItem != null)
            {
                CheckBox chkBox = (CheckBox)rpItem.FindControl("chkBoxID");
                chkBox.DoSomethingHere...
            }
   }
```

You Can Do it Like this way ....